# C# winforms TreeView sometimes selects wrong item

Tags: c#, treeview

I have winforms project with TreeView in it. Sometimes when I select some item other Item gets selected. I am very sure that there is not any code which could override the selection.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qutmu0tmrkjspc6/disablederrortreeview.rar?dl=0

Here is example project. I need to update the treeview so there is timer which regurarly updates its content (so once per second items gets deselected) but when clicking fast enough sometimes it select different item, that I didn't click.

Anyone knows what the problem could be? Is there any workaround/fix, that could prevent this?

Thank you

Jakub

Comment: I'm not going to dig into your project. But if there is a 1Hz Timer running in parallel to the user clicks I certainly would expect interference.. Maybe you can stop/start the timer upon enter/leave..?

Answer (score 0):

Two courses of action:

You can either: While the selection is happening disable the `Tick` event:

```
bool selecting = false;

private void treeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    selecting = true;
}

private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    selecting = false;
    // maybe you want to call the Tick now: 
    // timer1_Tick(null, null);
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (selecting) return;
    // do your stuff
    ..
}
```

Alternatively you could disable selecting while the `Tick` is running:

```
bool ticking = false;
TreeNode clickedNode = null;

private void treeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = ticking;
    clickedNode = e.Node;
}


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ticking = true;
    // do your stuff
    ticking = false;
    // try to select the clicked node
    if (clickedNode != null) 
      { treeView1.SelectedNode = clickedNode; clickedNode = null;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I am afraid, that timer does not cause the problem. Even when you disable the Timer, when clicking on TreeView it sometimes selects wrong item.

Comment: In that case there must be code somewhere that messes things up. Do look into the Before/AfterSelection events and also maybe other suspects like the Click, MouseUp/Down/Click events..

Comment: That is why I created this app, there is no code that modifies the TreeView, except Timer Tick, which happens only once per second. So except the ticks it should not interfere with user clicks. I guess it is some weird winforms bug, It maybe is fixed in WPF, but I must use winforms.